# Hacer Insert y Update en el mismo Observer, laravel

Tags: laravel

Como están, estoy un poco enredado con lo siguiente: Tengo un formulario mediante el cual hago "Traspaso de Materiales" de un técnico a otro, es decir en un select selecciono al técnico a, en otro el técnico b y en un select "materiales" cargo los materiales del técnico (desde la tabla stock_bodega_movil).

Para esto tengo las siguientes tablas involucradas: transferencia, det_transferencia y stock_bodega_movil(que guarda la cantidad de productos, el id_del producto y el id del técnico)

Bien, mediante un observer lo que necesito es que cuando se haga el insert en la tabla det_transferencia el observer me haga el insert en la tabla stock_bodega_tecnico (sera una nueva fila ya que el tecnico sera otro) y que a su vez descuente del tecnico a la cantidad transferida...

Por ahora el observer lo tengo asi:

```
 public function created(DetTransferenciaTecnico $detTransferenciaTecnico)
    {
        //
        $stock = StockBodegaMovil::firstOrNew([
            'material_id' => $detTransferenciaTecnico->material_id,
            'tecnico_id' => $detTransferenciaTecnico->tecnico_id
            ]);
            $stock->cantidad =  $stock->cantidad + $detTransferenciaTecnico->cantidad;
            $stock->save();
    }
```

Funciona ya que hace el nuevo insert pero no se como hacer para que también descuente la cantidad del técnico a...

**EDIT:** estoy probando con este codigo en un observer que se dispara cuando se hace el insert en la tabla stock_bodega_tecnico, la idea es que en la variable $material HAGO LA CONSULTA A LA FILA QUE DEBERIA ACTUALIZAR, la prueba y me trae la fila correcta, pero de ahi en mas no se como hacer para hacer el update

DB::table('stock_bodega_movils')
->where('material_id', $stockBodegaMovil->material_id)
->where('tecnico_id', '<>', $stockBodegaMovil->tecnico_id)
->decrement('cantidad', $stockBodegaMovil->cantidad);

Lo que me da como resultado lo siguiente, se inserta una nueva fila (id53) y se hace el descuento en la fila id1 (lo que es correcto) :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al probar nuevamente es decir al traspasar nuevamente, la fila id53 la cantidad deberia volver a 0 (no sucede) y la cantidad en la fila id1 deberia pasar a 1 (que si sucede) y todo queda asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Saludos a todos

Comment: supongo que todo eso lo tienes relacionado dentro de tus modelos. Simplemente debes hacer uso de la referencia que le das a tus materiales y así como sumas, luego lo restas, haciendo algo como `$stock->tecnico()->where('id', $id)->update([ 'cantidad_material' => //cantidad a restar ]);`

Comment: Ahí está el drama, no está relacionado vía modelos pprnoo que veo

Comment: Si no está por modelos puedes utilizar query builder, que te permitirá trabajar directamente con las tablas de forma sencilla y similar a los modelos. [Documentación a query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#select-statements).

Comment: si de hecho estoy trabajando por ese medio, pero no logro hacer la actualziacion, me inserta bien la nueva fila pero no logro hacer el update...pense en un disparador directamente en mysql que se lanze cuando se haga un insert nuevo en la tabla stock, pero tampoco el disparador me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que haces al final no es una actualización, estás creando una nueva instancia y utilizando `save()` al final. Prueba utilizando `decrement()`:

```
DB::table('stock_bodega_movils')
    ->where('material_id', $stockBodegaMovil->material_id)
    ->where('tecnico_id', '<>', $stockBodegaMovil->tecnico_id)
    ->decrement('cantidad', $stockBodegaMovil->cantidad);
```

Sugerencia:

Tu modelo `DetTransferenciaTecnico` debería tener los campos siguientes:

- Cantidad transferida.
- Id del material.
- Id del técnico al que se le transfiere.
- Id del técnico al que se le descuenta.

Dicho eso, tu método `created()` debería ser así:

```
public function created(DetTransferenciaTecnico $detTransferenciaTecnico) {
    $stock = StockBodegaMovil::firstOrNew([
            'material_id' => $detTransferenciaTecnico->material_id,
            'tecnico_id' => $detTransferenciaTecnico->to_tecnico_id
        ]);
        $stock->cantidad += $detTransferenciaTecnico->cantidad;
        $stock->save();

    DB::table('stock_bodega_movils')
        ->where('material_id', $detTransferenciaTecnico->material_id)
        ->where('tecnico_id', $detTransferenciaTecnico->from_tecnico_id)
        ->decrement('cantidad', $detTransferenciaTecnico->cantidad);
}
```

Debes notar que los cambios principales son `to_tecnico_id` y `from_tecnico_id`.

Comment: Hola, sabes que funciona una vez, pero luego al volver a hacer el proceso, este hace un insert en lugar de hacer el update

Comment: coloque unas imagenes y explique un pokito mas que sucede

Comment: si hago un dd($stockBodegaMovil->cantidad) si me imprime la cantidad

Comment: ahi me pierdo, no se si estoy llegando a la fila correcta

Comment: Actualizaré mi respuesta con una sugerencia.

Comment: mira si hago un dd de este codigo: $fila = StockBodegaMovil::where('tecnico_id','<>',$stockBodegaMovil->tecnico_id)
        ->where('material_id',$stockBodegaMovil->material_id)->first(); me muestra la fila que se deberia actualizar

Comment: Gracias, al parecer funciona impecablemente!!!